# Do WAFs block base64 encoded inputs?

Tags: waf

Do WAFs block/trigger alerts when they just read base64/hex encoded stuff as suspicious input? Or do they decode the strings (the ones which can do that), analyze the result and just then evetually block/trigger some alerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### That depends entirely on how the WAF is configured.

When you ask "Do WAFs *do this thing*?", you speak of them as if there were one and only one way to implement them.

In general, a WAF has to be configured for the application in question. For example, a WAF may be configured to block as soon as it sees bits of SQL syntax, as it may be indicative of attempted SQL injection.

This would be *terrible* in an SQL administration tool, which is used to configure queries in a database. But from the point of view of the WAF, both are just "SQL syntax in a POST request".

So the WAF needs to be configured for what is legitimate and what is not. If your application regularly transmits base64-encoded data, then that is legitimate and will likely not trigger an alert. If it doesn't then it *might* trigger one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it affected also the response from the web application? I mean, webapp X usually does not respond with anything in base64, could it trigger the WAF which protects that webapp?

Comment: Usually, WAF only blocks in terms of requests, not responses.